# Removing XML namespace from WebApi

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with a WebApi and XML as result.

I just keep receiving a weird namespace in my result, for exemple:

```
<QueryId>FE04A4E6-A584-47BF-9DA1-7360DFB08A8D</QueryId>
<ExecutionError>true</ExecutionError>
<OperationResult xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyTypes" i:nil="true"/>
<ErrorMessage>INVALID ACCOUNT</ErrorMessage>
```

I read some solutions and included this at my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

But using this parameter, my return was the same without OperationResult tag (the only one that was not filled out):

```
<QueryId>FE04A4E6-A584-47BF-9DA1-7360DFB08A8D</QueryId>
<ExecutionError>true</ExecutionError>
<ErrorMessage>INVALID ACCOUNT</ErrorMessage>
```

I was trying to use my result object like this:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class CustomRecordResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public string             QueryId         { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool               ExecutionError  { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string             ErrorMessage    { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public CustomSourceRecord OperationResult { get; set; }
}
```

But it´s not working. My result object is empty in this case

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [EmitDefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue.aspx) option to control whether that member will be serialized when it is null.

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public CustomSourceRecord OperationResult { get; set; }
```